# C++ clean way to define table of ifloats as array

Tags: c++

I have a table like this:

```
static const float scalers[NUM_Categories] = { 0.f,   0.97f, 0.92f, 0.83f,
                                                 0.94f, 0.73f, 0.9f};
```

What is the cleanest way to define this? It's a global.

I was thinking of something like

```
static const float scalers[NUM_Categories] = { [Category_A] 0.f,   
[Category_B] 0.97f, [Category_C] 0.92f, [Category_D] 0.83f,
                                                 [Category_E] 0.94f, [Category_F] 0.73f, [Category_G] 0.9f };
```

But that iirc is nonstandard C. The project in question compiles with clang, gcc, and msvc (As C++). Is there some way to have something similar that makes it easy to tell which values in the array correspond to which categories at a glance? (While keeping it a simple array)

Comment: Are you looking for [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers)? That won't work in C++ (for an array).

Comment: you could use a map instead of an array

Comment: Designated array initializers have existed in C since the C99 standard. It haven't been added (for arrays) in C++ yet. Note that the designators must be compile-time constants, like enumeration symbols.

Comment: I do not understand question. What is wrong with initial version? What are this `[Category_<X>]`?

Comment: @Nelfeal I'm looking for alternatives

Comment: @MarekR Readability

Comment: @idclev463035818 I considered that but I feel like moving to a map just for this is kinda overkill, that is why I mentioned "while keeping it a simple array". Thank you for your answer anyways.

Comment: @NicolásAbram: Meanwhile, C++20 has been released, which now allows designated initializers also in C++, but not just in C. I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use a `std::array` instead, you can initialize it with a function, in which you can specify elements one at a time.

```
constexpr auto init_scalers() -> std::array<float, NUM_Categories> {
    auto scalers = std::array<float, NUM_Categories>{};
    scalers[Category_A] = 0.f;
    scalers[Category_B] = 0.97f;
    return scalers;
}

static constexpr std::array<float, NUM_Categories> scalers = init_scalers();
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ceebf0f3f9b37cf7)

You can also use a lambda.

```
static constexpr std::array<float, NUM_Categories> scalers = []{
    auto scalers = std::array<float, NUM_Categories>{};
    scalers[Category_A] = 0.f;
    scalers[Category_B] = 0.97f;
    return scalers;
}();
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68fd62c5fdd9f39c)

Comment: I think this is sadly the closest thing to what I was looking for, despite the syntax soup. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> Is there some way to have something similar that makes it easy to tell which values in the array correspond to which categories at a glance? (While keeping it a simple array)

You can use code formatting and comments, like this:

```
static const float scalers[NUM_Categories] = {
    0.0f,   //Category_A
    0.97f, //Category_B
    0.92f, //Category_C
    0.83f, //Category_D
    0.94f, //Category_E
    0.73f, //Category_F
    0.9f   //Category_G
};
```

UPDATE:
Meanwhile, the new ISO C++20 standard has been released, which now allows [designated initializers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization#Designated_initializers). Up to then, they only existed in C, but not C++.

If your compiler supports C++20, you can now write the following:

```
enum
{
    CATEGORY_A,
    CATEGORY_B,
    CATEGORY_C,
    CATEGORY_D,
    CATEGORY_E,
    CATEGORY_F,
    CATEGORY_G,
    NUM_CATEGORIES
};

static const float scalers[NUM_CATEGORIES] = {
    [CATEGORY_A] = 0.0f,
    [CATEGORY_B] = 0.97f,
    [CATEGORY_C] = 0.92f,
    [CATEGORY_D] = 0.83f,
    [CATEGORY_E] = 0.94f,
    [CATEGORY_F] = 0.73f,
    [CATEGORY_G] = 0.9f
};
```

Note that C++ requires that when using designated initializers, they not be declared out of order. This is not required in C.